# Is there a character limit on the number of ORs you can include in a google search URL

Tags: google-search

I'm trying create google search with MANY "OR"s
sorted by date

My results are inconsistent.

Is this because there is a character limit?

+OR+cat+OR+dog+OR+zebra..................

*Fwiw, I'm tracking news articles if that makes any difference.

Here's an example

[image]